# Global variable in Zend Controller

Tags: zend-framework

```
   class UserController extends Zend_Controller_Action
  {
      protected $varGlobal;
      public function oneAction()
      {
           $this->varGlobal=0;

           .........
       }
      public function twoAction()
       {
            $temp=$this->varGlobal;//temp return null;
        }

  }
```

how do i keep value of varGlobal after excuted oneAction()?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could also try static properties :

```
class UserController extends Zend_Controller_Action
  {
      protected static $varGlobal;
      public function init(){
            self::$varGlobal=0;
      }
      public function oneAction()
      {
           self::$varGlobal=15;

           .........
       }
      public function twoAction()
       {
            $temp=self::$varGlobal;//temp return 0,don't change value after excute oneaction();
        }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `$this->varGlobal` persists as long as you call `twoAction` method on same object. For every request new object gets created. so if your next request goes to twoAction, one action won't gets fired.

In order to set the variable for every object, you could use `init` function and initialize variables there.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use Zend_Controller_Action::_setParam() and Zend_Controller_Action::_getParam() ?
or Zend_Registry ?